# Stain Grade Door - piece of veneer missing - how best to repair?

Tags: repair, doors, veneer

I have a brand new door stain grade vertical grain fir or hemlock.  Any thoughts on how best to handle this damage?  I am not sure if the door came like this or if it was damaged by the door installer.  A replacement door is probably close to $800 after delivery.  It is the bottom of the door on the room side face of the door so I am not sure anyone but me would notice.

[image: bottom door damage]

Comment: A kick plate might solve this

Answer (score 2):

For minor repairs I have used lacquer sticks with much success. There are videos of people who really know how to use the sticks to make repairs like you need. You could try it yourself with practice. The sticks are not a big investment.

Paint could be used too, as in faux finish, but that is definitely an acquired touch.